# Mostrar dados do meu site em outros sites

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget

Tenho um site onde quero disponibilizar um widget (ou algo assim). 
Quero fazer mais ou menos como alguns sites fazem:
Dão um link de JS + uma div para o usuário. Ele simplesmente coloca no site e aparecem os dados.

Meu site é PHP, eu já consegui pegar uns dados com JQuery Load assim:

`$("#divTestArea2").load("http://meusite.com/paginadedados #dados");`

Como vocês podem ver é um load simples (mas pega o que quero). 
Agora que não consegui mais achar nada na Internet. Gostaria de manipular o CSS dos dados.

Esta página de dados é bem simples-- tem apenas marcação de Divs sem CSS

```
<div id="dados">

    <div id="iddoprimeirodado">
        Dado1
    </div>
    <div id="iddosegundodado">
        Dado2
    </div>
</div>
```

Quando faço o load aparece os dados sem formatação.

Como faço para formatar no JS acima, e já aparecer correto no site do meu usuário? O que tenho que por no meu código? Eu andei procurando muito, e não achei nada que eu pudesse entender, já que estou iniciando com JS e Jquery.

E é claro que eu gostaria de construir os links, enviando para meu site.

Infelizmente a documentação é vaga e não achei nada especifico para isso.
Como devo pesquisar? Onde acho documentação mais especifica pra isso?

Desde já agradeço. Abraços

Comment: Olá, já tentou fazer algo do tipo? `$("#divTestArea2").load("http://meusite.com/paginadedados #dados", function(){
   $("#divTestArea2").css("atributo_css", "valor");
});`

Comment: Eu tinha tentando fazer, mas percebi que fiz de maneira errada.
Agora deu certo. Obrigado

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes seu comentário parece ser a solução do problema do autor da pergunta. Talvez fosse uma boa você criar uma resposta mesmo para deixá-la oficializada.

Comment: @Uriel a resposta do Guilherme resolveu seu problema?

Answer (score 1):

Como foi sugerido estou formalizando a resposta:

Teste desta maneira:

```
$("#divTestArea2").load("http://meusite.com/paginadedados #dados", function(){
   $("#divTestArea2").css("atributo_css", "valor");
});
```